# Is there ever a reason to use tmpfs instead of or in addition to zRAM?

Tags: swap, tmpfs

I'm thinking about using [zRam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/zRam) on my server.
From what I've read about zRam, it apparently does everything [tmpfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/tmpfs) does and more.

Once zRAM is working, is there any reason to keep tmpfs around?
Is there anything tmpfs does that zRAM can't do?
Is there ever a reason to use tmpfs instead of or in addition to zRAM?

Answer (score 7):

Data written to a `tmpfs` will be kept in-memory uncompressed as long as enough memory is available. Once the system comes under memory pressure, it tries to move data from the `tmpfs` (and from any other places, like normal process memory) to any `swap` (including `swap` on `zram`) it can find. Also you can change parameters of a `tmpfs` by doing a simple `mount -o remount`, especially the size of the file system or the number of inodes.

Using `zram` as the backing of a temporary file system has the disadvantage, that all data written there needs to be compressed immediatelly (and decompressed upon use). Also you need to put a file system on top, whiches structures need to be stored even if there are no actual files stored. Also you get limitations like max number of inodes, you can't easily change it's size and so on.

IMHO, best solution is to mount `tmpfs` somewhere to use and create a `zram` swap. It combines the advantages of both by minimizing the disadvantages.

Or buy more ram of couse ;)

Answer (score 0):

You will get better performance from using `zram` for `swap` due to the compression that is possible.

[`zram-init`](https://github.com/vaeth/zram-init) makes `zram` simple to use. Remember to [read the instructions](https://github.com/vaeth/zram-init/blob/master/openrc/conf.d/zram-init).

Your kernel needs to be built with `CONFIG_ZRAM_LZ4_COMPRESS` enabled to be able to benefit from [`lz4` compression](http://it-offshore.co.uk/linux/alpine-linux/74-alpine-linux-zram-with-lz4-compression).

I use `zram` for `swap` & for `/tmp` (`zram-init` uses [sensible default mount options](https://github.com/vaeth/zram-init/commit/ee5445f9164819c342d6f38bd94c86dc0afb8cf5) for `/tmp`):

```
root@alpine [~]# cat /proc/swaps
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/vda7                               partition   1045500 0   -1
/dev/zram0                              partition   1048572 0   16383
root@alpine [~]# mount|grep zram
/dev/zram1 on /tmp type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,discard)
```

There are still use cases for using `tmpfs`. I use these for bind mounting volumes with secure mount options into `lxc` containers:

```
root@http [~]# mount|grep tmpfs
tmpfs on /var/www/domain.com/bin type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=200k)
tmpfs on /var/www/domain.comm/dev type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=4k,mode=755)
```

Comment: What you say is true. But I don't see how it's relevant to my question about tmpfs. Did you perhaps mean to post this as an answer to some other question?

Comment: @David Cary - answer expanded

Comment: Is "There is never any reason to use tmpfs. Instead, zram is just as easy to use and gives better performance" a valid summary? Because I'm not seeing any reasons to use tmpfs in your answer. (It may be obvious to you the reasons why using tmpfs is a great idea "for bind mounting volumes with secure mount options into lxc containers", but I wish you would tell me what those reasons are. Or is there no actual reason, and you're still doing it that way only because you haven't had time to convert that system zram?)

Comment: perhaps you should try actually using them both.